# Add space to <select> with ng-options

Tags: angularjs

How do I add leading spaces into the `<select>` options using Angular ng-options?

```
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
    Static values (works)
    <select>
        <option value="black">black</option>
        <option value="white">&nbsp;white</option>
        <option value="red">&nbsp;&nbsp;red</option>
        <option value="blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;blue</option>
        <option value="yellow">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;yellow</option>
    </select>

    Values from JS using angular (only the first-default works)
    <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name for c in colors">
        <option value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;default</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    angular.module("myApp", []).
    controller("MyCntrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.colors = [{
            name: 'black',
            shade: 'dark'
        }, {
            name: '&nbsp;white',
            shade: 'light'
        }, {
            name: '&nbsp;&nbsp;red',
            shade: 'dark'
        }, {
            name: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;blue',
            shade: 'dark'
        }, {
            name: '       yellow', // spaces here
            shade: 'light'
        }];
    }]);
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can format the option text:

```
<select ng-model="color" ng-options="('&nbsp;'+c.name) for c in colors">
    <option value="">&nbsp;default</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to generate the `&nbsp;` dynamically it is a little bit more complicated. Suppose you have a function in your controller that knows how many `&nbsp;` you want to add, then you can write this function like this:

```
$scope.addSpaces= function(color){
    var count = 1;// put your logic here
    var result = "";
    for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
        result+= String.fromCharCode(160);
    }
    return result;
};
```

in your html it will be:

```
<select ng-model="color" ng-options="(addSpaces(c)+c.name) for c in colors">
    <option value="">&nbsp;default</option>
</select>
```

This works because we concatenate the unicode character for `&nbsp;` (e.g. `&#160;`) in our string and not the entity, so there is nothing to escape for the `element.text()` function.

Comment: Thanks, this could be handy, but still, how do I add different number of spaces? For example 1 space before white, 2 spaces before red, 3 spaces before blue... That I guess has to be done in the JS, but whatever I try return literally &nbsp; visible in the options.

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(160)` - that's what I was missing all the time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can also just put the 160 character into your name strings in $scope.colors

Comment: Fantastic, had the logic already set up an this helped me work it into the select, cheers.