# How to add HTML entities in Angular select with ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, html-entities, ng-options

My question is somehow related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21304681/1446845), although slightly different.

What I would like to achieve is to get HTML entities parsed from a string passed to a `select` with `ng-options`. So given these data:

```
$scope.myOptions = [{
   text: '10.00 &euro;',
   val: 10
},{
   text: '25.00 &euro;',
   val: 25
},{
   text: '50.00 &euro;',
   val: 50
}];
```

And this template:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="desiredAmount" 
        ng-options="opt.val as opt.text for opt in myOptions">
</select>
```

I would like the `&euro;` entity to be displayed as €, while here this does not happen (and I can understand why, as Angular correctly interprets my data as a simple string). Is it possible to solve this?

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gubeqa/2/edit) I have made to isolate my problem.

**PS** - I know that I can achieve it using

```
<option ng-repeat="opt in myOptions">{{opt.text}} &euro;</option>
```

But this arises another problem with the appearance of a first empty option which is why I'd like to stick to the `ng-option` method, and in any case I would like to know if it is even possible to get a string parsed when using `ng-option`.

Comment: If you want just an empty option first, you could just add an empty option element before ng-repeat no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $sce, to format the euro sign.

in HTML:

```
  <select>
      <option ng-repeat="opt in myOptions" ng-bind-html="htmlAdText(opt.text)">{{opt.text}}</option>
  </select>
```

in JS:

```
  $scope.desiredAmount = $scope.myOptions[0].text;

  $scope.htmlAdText = function(text){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
  }
```

Don't forget to inject $sce into your controller.

http://jsbin.com/tijevebiya/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

As regards as euro problem, you can also use a filter to display the value. This filtre is currency and put all value in this format : $0.00. Moreover you can also change the currency symbol.

You can do it like this :

```
{{opt.val | currency:"€"}}
```

You can find more information here :

> http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:currency